# `if` statement not working correctly

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to make a console application for my programming class. The if statement is not working correctly. I want it to count the string length and if it's greater than 10000 or less than 0, go to the else statement. But it doesn't and continues the if statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input a year from 0 to 10000 to determine the next year with distinct numbers");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();

    int MaxLength = 10000;
    int MinLength = 0;

    if (a.Length <= MaxLength && a.Length >= MinLength)
    {
        string b = a.Substring(0, 1);
        string b1 = a.Substring(1, 1);
        string b2 = a.Substring(2, 1);
        string b3 = a.Substring(3, 1);

        Console.WriteLine(b + " " + b1 + " " + b2 + " " + b3);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? What is the value of `a.Length`?

Comment: Sample input and output please. Plus you are treating the string length as if it were the literal number represented by the string, `Length` doesn't get the integer value of a string number, it gets the length of the string based on the character count. You need to `int b = int.Parse(a);` and use `b` in the checks...

Comment: Have you tried to debug your application?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong idea. If you are asking the user to input *numbers* from `0` up to `10000`, then you need to convert your `string` from `ReadLine` into an integer, then you can compare the integers.

Comment: @SonerGönül The a.Length is 6 when I input 100001. I want it so if the input is 100001 or more then it jumps to the else statement.

Comment: Good luck trying to get a *length* of less than zero ;) But obviously you don't mean "length" anyway, you mean value (as the answers suggest)

Comment: @kolton The length of a `string` and the value of it (numerical) values are completely different things. You don't need to use `Length` at all. Just parse your `a` to `int` and compare _that_ value with your `MaxLength` and `MinLength` values as others said.

Comment: @SonerGönül But I can't use the Substring method with an integer.

Comment: You can. use `a.ToString().Substring`.

Comment: @kolton, Soner is on the right track.  Use the parsed integer to compare with zero and 10,000...  then go back to the original input string to break out the substrings

Comment: @Joe Yeah, parsing the string allows it to do what I want. Thanks for everyone's help! :D

Comment: What if input is "10"? `a.Substring(3, 1);` will throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You need to check for that.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I know, I'm not worried about that at the moment. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `int.Parse(a)`.

```
if (int.Parse(a) <= MaxLength && int.Parse(a) >= MinLength)
{
    string b = a.Substring(0, 1);
    string b1 = a.Substring(1, 1);
    string b2 = a.Substring(2, 1);
    string b3 = a.Substring(3, 1);

    Console.WriteLine(b + " " + b1 + " " + b2 + " " + b3);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: Seems like a waste to parse twice. OP is fresh, so it's good opportunity to install good habits ;)  ...though I can't even guess at the purpose of those substring values :/

Comment: @musefan I'm Substringing the values so I can later compare them to see if the value the user inputs has any duplicates. I was just worried about the 'if' statement not working correctly.

Comment: oh, didn't even notice at first, but the logic is wrong. The condition will never be true!

Comment: @musefan Corrected it now.

Comment: Another good habit to get the OP into: DRY. `int.Parse`ing twice is bad form. Heck, `int.Parse` user input is bad form full stop - use `int.TryParse`

Comment: @kolton - I just realized that this still needs some work.  What if the user enters "25"?  The first two substrings will work, the 3rd and 4th will error out.  This is where you want to use the Length.  if the Length is less than 4, you probably want to Left-Pad the string with zeroes.

Comment: @Joe for that, one would need `a.ToString("00000");`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking the *length of the string input* - so if a user enters, for example, `100` the length will be three.

A length of a string can never be less than zero, and I very much doubt it will ever be longer than 10000.

Perhaps what you were actually trying to do is convert the user's entry to a number, while also keeping th ability to use the `Substring` method from the users input as a set of characters.

In which case, you want 2 variables

1. The original user input (a string, where you can use `Substring`) - `a` from your original code
2. A *numerical* representation of the input for which you can compare to a min & max number. `val` in the code below

Another consideration is that the user may enter a value which is not convertable to a number, so

3. A boolean indicating that the user has entered a valid number. `isValidEntry` in the code below

---

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a year from 0 to 10000 to determine the next year with distinct numbers");
string a = Console.ReadLine();

int MaxLength = 10000;
int MinLength = 0;
int val = 0;
bool isValidEntry = int.TryParse(a, out val);

if (isValidEntry && val <= MaxLength && val >= MinLength)
{
    string b = a.Substring(0, 1);
    string b1 = a.Substring(1, 1);
    string b2 = a.Substring(2, 1);
    string b3 = a.Substring(3, 1);

    Console.WriteLine(b + " " + b1 + " " + b2 + " " + b3);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This is the start of a good answer, shame it's incomplete because I don't really want to write my own when this one already has potential. I really think you should be showing how to do the number conversion aspect to make it a complete answer

Comment: @musefan was updating as you commented.

Comment: You are the only one who got your condition the right way around!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some confusion on what you are doing. Your description says you are trying to count the amount of characters in the inputed string. In which case you will need a string with more that 10000 characters to go the else statement.

However your program code claims you just want the numerical value of your string. Therefore you should try using a conversion method.

```
int x = int.Parse(a);
```

Obviously you need to do bound checking on x instead of a afterwards.